# Problem with NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication in Swift under BigSur

Tags: swift

I try to start the Preview App from within my Swift-App.
I think it worked like this before updating to BigSur (unfortunately I cannot test it in a prior OS).

The App shall be able to show any file in the filesystem with the Preview-App.

What I tried:

- removed Sandbox from the targets capabilities
- added iCloud Documents
- added com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write with the value "/" to the entitlements.

```
func openPreviewApp(path : String)
{
  let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Applications/Preview.app", isDirectory: true) as URL
  let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
  configuration.arguments = [path]
  NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url,
                                     configuration: configuration,
                                     completionHandler: nil)

}
```

The function opens the Preview App but not the file given in path - instead the fileselection dialog is presented.

open -a Preview  THISPATH in Terminal works fine.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @ElTomato.  I removed the Sandbox from the targets capabilities and added iCloud Documents for those folders. That seem not to be enough. My App wants to show any file in the filesystem (with the Preview-App) - how can I grant that privilege?